# VSTS - How to write a build defintion with phases that focus on their own exclusive projects of the same solution?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a solution which has a .netcore2.1 webapi and a xamarin.iOS app.
These projects don't depend on each others (not entirely true as they reference a shared project, but that should be irrelevant for the question).

My vsts build definition is made of two phases:

- one to build the webapi (called azureAndBackend) on the vsts Hosted VS2017 queue
- another one to build the app (called iOS) on the vsts Hosted macOS Preview queue

```
- phase: azureAndBackend
  displayName: Azure and backend
  queue:
    name: Hosted VS2017
...
- phase: iOS
  displayName: iOS 
  dependsOn: azureAndBackend
  queue:
    name: Hosted macOS Preview
```

The azureAndBackend phase is fine.
However the ios phase fails at the `dotnet restore` task:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: NuGet restore
  inputs:
      restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
```

Indeed it restores packages for the whole solution (so webapi included) whereas .netcore 2.1 sdk is not installed on the Hosted macOS Preview queue yet (see that [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-Readme.md) page).

So I tried the following:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: NuGet restore
  inputs:
      restoreSolution: '**/*.iOS/*.csproj'
```

Then the restore step is ok.
However now the build step fails:

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
    displayName: 'Building iOS'
    inputs:
        solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
        configuration: 'iOS'
```

the error being:

```
'/Users/vsts/agent/2.134.2/work/1/s/MyApp.Services.Interfaces/obj/project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

Note that `iOS` configuration is a copy of the `Release` configuration but where I don't build the webapi project.

The question is how to write my build definition as if there were not webapi project in the solution?

UPDATE

I think a workaround would be to create 3 solutions

- the one I already have and develop on
- one with the iOS project only
- one with the webapi project only

Then phases would build their own solution.
This is not the "real" answer to the question though.

Answer (score 0):

For all tasks, make sure you point to the specific solution files and solution directories. Your `**/*.sln` will build all solutions in the sources folder.

Comment: The `DotNetCoreCli` task focus on project files, which is nice, whereas the `XamariniOs` task focus on solution files which is the source of my issue.